# Haskell Generic Type

Tags: function, haskell, types

So I just started learning Haskell and I have been stuck on this for quite some time already. So I have a function that calculates a number after an offset has been minus (minimum value is 0). I managed to do this function with the types explicitly shown.

```
offSetter :: Int -> Int -> Int
offSetter number offset
    | number - offset >= 0 = number - offset
    | otherwise = 0
```

But when I tried to change it to use generic types as below, it keeps giving me an error. Am I doing it wrong?

```
offSetter :: Num a => a -> a -> a
offSetter number offset
    | number - offset >= 0 = number - offset
    | otherwise = 0
```

The error I'm getting:

```
* Could not deduce (Ord a) arising from a use of '>='
      from the context: Num a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   offSetter :: forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a
        at src\test.hs:57:1-33
      Possible fix:
        add (Ord a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            offSetter :: forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a
    * In the expression: number - offset >= 0
      In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                     an equation for `offSetter':
        number - offset >= 0
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It suggested me to use ord? updated with error :)

Comment: Have you tried following the advice of the compiler?

Comment: `>=` is not applicable to all numbers, what about complex ones. Hence Num and Ord are separate independent things in Haskell.

Comment: Update: I finally manage to solve it!!!! I use         offSetter :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> a -> a .. So Ord is used because there are elements like Strings that is not applicable to Num?

Comment: Put the answer in the answer section for the next learner. Good job!

Answer (score 4):

Solved it by adding Ord a:

```
offSetter :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> a -> a
offSetter number1 offSet
    | number1 - offSet >= 0 = number1 - offSet
    | otherwise = 0
```

Comment: That's perfect. You have to do this because although (as far as I know) there are no stdlib types that implement `Num` and not `Ord`, it's not outside of the realm of possibility that there would be something `Num`y that's not orderable.

Comment: @AdamSmith `Complex` is in the standard library and implements `Num` but not `Ord`. (This is because it is not possible to make an `Ord` instance that has the property that if `a <= b` and `c <= d` then `a+c <= b+d`; I think it's a bad reason, but that's the reason.)

Comment: @DanielWagner `Ord` codifies a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order), and there's no "sensible" total order on the complex numbers. Yours is a [partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set). One could generalize `offSetter` e.g. by using `abs number1 >= abs offSet` instead of `number1 - offset >= 0`, then it doesn't need a total ordering.

Comment: @dirkt You say "Yours is a partial order.". But I didn't say what mine was. So how can you know that? You say "There's no 'sensible' total order on the complex numbers.". What does "sensible" mean? I assume you mean "that has the property that if `a <= b` and `c <= d` then `a+c <= b+d`"; if so, I'm well aware that no total order has that property, as you can see from my previous comment where I myself point that out. But I don't think that's an important property for an `Ord` instance to have -- and it certainly isn't promised by the documentation for `Ord`!

Comment: @DanielWagner dirkt is talking about the properties of complex numbers, not the properties of total orders. There is no total order defined for complex numbers. This comes straight from the mathematics and has nothing to do with Haskell, per se. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order for more information about what we mean by "total order". The `Ord` class in Haskell implements the mathematical properties of a total order.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice That is not correct. There's many perfectly good total orders on complex numbers, provided the wrapped type itself has a total order. `compare (a :+ b) (c :+ d) = compare (a, b) (c, d)` is one.

Comment: @DanielWagner Okay, I spoke too quickly. Still if there are "many good total orders" on complex numbers how do you choose one of these as the canonical one?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice There are also many good total orders on tuples. Should we avoid defining `instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Ord (a, b)`?

Answer (score 4):

As you discovered, you need to add the type class `Ord` as a constraint to the type `a` with the following type signature:

```
offSetter :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> a -> a
```

This is because `Ord` is the typeclass with comparison operators like `(>=)`.

> So Ord is used because there are elements like Strings that is not applicable to Num?

No, since `String` is not a member of the `Num` typeclass, the original declaration already excludes it as a possible candidate for the type `a`. As I stated earlier, you need to use `Ord` in order to guarantee that the type `a` has the operator `(>=)` available.